# Assigning new creation file time on tar extraction

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

Does anybody know how i can tell tar to assign a new creation date to extracted files?

Let's say I have an archive filled with old files of varying ages. Upon extraction 
I want all files to have the same time stamp (that of the time of the extraction).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out. The answer is  the touch option -m or --touch.